# Seperate records from a dictionary when a specific condition is met, and use that dictionary for replacing words in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-re

1st problem

I have a dictionary ready. i want to separate records based on a particular key value pair.
Example

```
dict = [{'NAME':'APPLE','COLOR' : 'RED', 'PRICE' : '100'},{'NAME':'MANGO','COLOR' : 'YELLOW', 'PRICE' : '300'},{'NAME':'CHERRY','COLOR' : 'RED', 'PRICE' : '250'}]
```

here I want to bifurcate records into other dictionary which has same colors
so i want the output to be something like this

```
dict_red_color = [{'NAME':'APPLE','COLOR' : 'RED', 'PRICE' : '100'},{'NAME':'CHERRY','COLOR' : 'RED', 'PRICE' : '250'}]
```

dict_yellow_color = [{'NAME':'MANGO','COLOR' : 'YELLOW', 'PRICE' : '300'}]

2nd problem ( Code is ready, but working with single dictionary )

```
import re

txt = "<I love *NAME*, it is *COLOR* in color, Its price is *PRICE*>"

dict = [{'NAME':'APPLE','COLOR' : 'RED', 'PRICE' : '100'},{'NAME':'MANGO','COLOR' : 'YELLOW', 'PRICE' : '300'},{'NAME':'CHERRY','COLOR' : 'RED', 'PRICE' : '250'}]

pattern = r"\*([^*]+)\*"

for d in dicts:
    print(re.sub(pattern, lambda match: d[match[1]], txt))
```

output is

```
"<I love APPLE, it is RED in color, Its price is 100>
 <I love MANGO, it is YELLOW in color, Its price is 300>"
```

This code takes only one text string and one dictionary into account, I want to do same thing, by first bifurcating the dict into 2 parts and then those two dict which we will make in 1st problem will be used with their respective text strings, which are :

```
text_for_red_color = ''' <I love *NAME*, the price is *PRICE* > '''
text_for_yellow_color = ''' <I don't love *NAME*, the price is *PRICE* > '''
```

2 dictionaries,

```
dict_red_color = [{'NAME':'APPLE','COLOR' : 'RED', 'PRICE' : '100'},{'NAME':'CHERRY','COLOR' : 'RED', 'PRICE' : '250'}]

dict_yellow_color = [{'NAME':'MANGO','COLOR' : 'YELLOW', 'PRICE' : '300'}]
```

to create the final output as,

```
output = ''' <I love Apple, the price is 100><I love Cherry, the price is 250><I don't love Mango, the price is 300> '''
```

Comment: "have not written the code yet" <- this is not a code-writing or tutorial service, and we ask that questions include a [mcve] with the code you've already tried based on your own research, so that we can better target our help to your need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your first problem

```
dict_red_color = [x for x in dict if x["COLOR"] == "RED"]
dict_yellow_color = [x for x in dict if x["COLOR"] == "YELLOW"]
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot.. please see if you can help me with the second problem in it

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use `re` here? Why not use string formatting? As for filtering the text based on the color use a dict with the colors as keys and the strings as values:

```
inputs = [{'NAME':'APPLE','COLOR' : 'RED', 'PRICE' : '100'},{'NAME':'MANGO','COLOR' : 'YELLOW', 'PRICE' : '300'},{'NAME':'CHERRY','COLOR' : 'RED', 'PRICE' : '250'}]

outputs = {'RED': "<I love {NAME}, the price is {PRICE} >", 'YELLOW': "<I don't love {NAME}, the price is {PRICE} >"}

for d in inputs:
    print(outputs[d['COLOR']].format(**d))
```

Output:

```
<I love APPLE, the price is 100 >
<I don't love MANGO, the price is 300 >
<I love CHERRY, the price is 250 >
```

Comment: how should i combine the yellow string too with its own dict

Comment: hey what if i have a number which is not an integer in my inputs . it is throwing me an error . TypeError: string indices must be integers .. what should i do ?